# How can I calculate this probability: $P(W_1<cW_2$) and $c\geq 0$?

Tags: probability, self-study, stochastic-processes

Let $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}, $ be a Brownian motion. I want to calculate the following:

$P(W_1<cW_2$)  and $c\geq 0$

For $c=1$ it is easy. I just write it as an increment, but how can I do it when $c$ is not one?

Comment: Because the joint distribution of any finite number of the $W_t$ is multivariate normal, *any* finite linear combination of them, such as $W_1-cW_2$, will have a Normal distribution of zero mean.  What is the chance that such a random variable is less than zero?

Answer (score 2):

Do a bit of algebraic manipulation and you'll get
$$
P((1-c)(W_1-W_0) < c(W_2-W_1)) 
$$
We know the $W_t$ are Brownian motion so, $W_1-W_0$ and $W_2-W_1$ are independent normal variables. Their means are 0, and their variances are 1 (because 1-0=2-1=1. W_3-W_1 would have variance 3-1=2).
So the probability is equal to
$$
P((1-c)Z_1 < c Z_2)
$$
where the $Z_i$ are just standard normal random variables.

Comment: This does not answer the question, does it? But simply postpones the moment when one will apply the argument, unmentioned here, showing that the result is 50%.

Comment: It's probably less than 50%, but the reduced problem is much much easier. You're no longer dealing with Wiener processes. (c-1)Z_1+cZ_2 is just a normal random variable, so calculating that is trivial.

Comment: "It's probably less than 50%" Wanna bet?

Comment: I'm sorry. I misspoke. I didn't mean the answer was 50%, I was referring to how much progress was made on the problem.